# Get the last element in json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

how can I get the last element in the json array in the seats object. I want to get the countryid of with the value of 845, however this json is dynamic so i want to get the last element in the seats object. My api is structured like this. Thank you in advance.

```
{
"expirationDate":"April 21, 2017",
"remainingDays":325,
"seats":[{"activeStatus":"S","pid":"TE70","firstName":"TE70","countryid":840},
        {"activeStatus":"Y","pid":"TE80","firstName":"TE80","countryid":845}]
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried indexing with `length - 1`?

Comment: yes i've tried, but i can't figure it out. thank you for your response.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do this by accessing the `jsonData.seats` array by index, index of the last item being equal to `jsonData.seats.length-1`

simply:

```
var countryId = jsonData.seats[jsonData.seats.length-1].countryid
```

Answer (score 3):

NB: Copy of @iuliu.net's code

use DOT at

`example.at(-1)`

```
 var jsonObject = {
        "expirationDate":"April 21, 2017",
        "remainingDays":325,
        "seats":[{"activeStatus":"S","pid":"TE70","firstName":"TE70","countryid":840},
                {"activeStatus":"Y","pid":"TE80","firstName":"TE80","countryid":845}]
                 }

var lastElement = jsonObject.seats.at(-1).countryid
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var jsonObject = {
"expirationDate":"April 21, 2017",
"remainingDays":325,
"seats":[{"activeStatus":"S","pid":"TE70","firstName":"TE70","countryid":840},
        {"activeStatus":"Y","pid":"TE80","firstName":"TE80","countryid":845}]
 }

var lastElement = jsonObject.seats[jsonObject.seats.length-1].countryid
```

Comment: returns undefined though :/

Comment: The two statements in themselves return undefined because they're just declarations of variables. You need to access the `lastElement` variable to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse array and then get first element: `el.reverse()[0]`

For your example:

```js
var jsonObject = {
  "expirationDate": "April 21, 2017",
  "remainingDays": 325,
  "seats": [
    {"activeStatus":"S","pid":"TE70","firstName":"TE70","countryid":840},
    {"activeStatus":"Y","pid":"TE80","firstName":"TE80","countryid":845},
  ]
}

console.log( jsonObject.seats.reverse()[0].countryid ); //845
```

Comment: Mutating an array in this way is inefficient

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to do this in JSONPath syntax, you can do this with `$.seats[-1:]`. If you wanted to do something like get the `countryid` attribute nested in the last element, it would be `$.seats[-1:][countryid]`.

This is handy for chaining requests when testing endpoints in an API Client.